# "Choose Application" functionality in Whats App

Tags: ios

I'm currently using Whats App on iOS, and notice that when ever a pin is shared and used the following is shown:

[image]

So I have a few questions:

1. How exactly is this being done? Is Whats App using the `canOpenURL` method which checks which apps can handle the geo pin?
2. Conversely how are Google Maps and Maps able to respond to this? Are they registering a specific URL schemes?

Any help or where or what to research would be great. Google's great when you know what you are looking for.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme

Comment: Regarding Apple Maps: [Apple URL Scheme Reference - Maps Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1)